# Getting coordinates of outside window

Tags: java

I know how to easily get the coordinates of a jPanel that you make in a program, but I am really trying to figure out how to get the coordinates of a window that isn't jPanel + jFrame; such as a window in Chrome or even just a directory (**not swing**).

Usually, I can find something online, but this seems to be a feature that perhaps Java cannot perform. I am looking for some higher knowledge about this.

Comment: Then either you didn't search hard enough or in the right direction, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091531/how-to-get-the-x-and-y-of-a-program-window-in-java)

Comment: Ha! Thanks I had a feeling that would happen. I really did search for a while for this and may not have been using the correct key words.

Comment: Perhaps you should try using a slightly nicer approach to responding to people's inquiries as well.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate it can be a little hard when you have no point to start from ;)

Comment: Also, I was looking for a little more Java and a little less import... I don't know why but I really like creating things myself. I know that it sounds particularly stupid - especially from a programmer - but I really like making things myself. Perhaps that is why I am so fond of assembly...Thank you for the site, though.

Comment: Also, sorry to keep commenting, but I downloaded and imported the .jar files and .zip files from github, but it doesn't work and I'm assuming it is because I am using a Mac; I think I read that JNA doesn't work for Mac (at least that's true for bringing a window to focus with JNA). Any thoughts?

Comment: You might need to have a look at [this](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/overview-summary.html), but yes, JNA supports Mac OS

Comment: You could also have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057817/using-jna-to-get-nswindow-from-jcomponent-on-mac)